# Vuex child components cannot access this.$store (undefined)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I followed [these instructions in the Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components) for accessing the Vuex state from my Vue components... but whenever I use `this.$store.something` in my components, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'something' of undefined` (see screenshot at the bottom of this post).

The documentation says,

> By providing the store option to the root instance, the store will be
>   injected into all child components of the root and will be available
>   on them as this.$store

...but that functionality does not seem to be working in my application.

Here is my code:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: null
  },
  mutations: { // setters (synchronous)
    setToken (state, userData) {
      state.token = userData.token
    },
    clearToken (state) {
      state.token = null
    }
  },
  actions: { // asynchronous tasks
    signup (authData) {
      axios.post('/user/signup', {
        email: authData.email,
        password: authData.password
      })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            // what happens if signup succeeds?
          } else {
            // what happens if signup fails?
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    setLogoutTimer ({commit}, expiresIn) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        commit('clearToken')
      }, expiresIn * 1000)
    },
    login ({commit, dispatch}, authData) {
      axios.post('/user/login', {
        email: authData.email,
        password: authData.password
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)

          // set token with timeout
          const now = new Date()
          const tokenExpiration = new Date(now.getTime() + res.data.expiresIn * 1000)
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
          localStorage.setItem('tokenExpiration', tokenExpiration)
          commit('setToken', { token: res.data.token })
          dispatch('setLogoutTimer', res.data.expiresIn)

          // redirect to dashboard
          router.replace('/dashboard')
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    tryAutoLogin ({commit}) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      if (!token) {
        return
      }
      const tokenExpiration = localStorage.getItem('tokenExpiration')
      const now = new Date()
      if (now >= tokenExpiration) {
        return
      }
      commit('setToken', { token: token })
    },
    logout ({commit}) {
      commit('clearToken')
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      localStorage.removeItem('tokenExpiration')
      router.replace('/login')
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated (state) {
      return state.token !== null
    }
  }
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header/>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'app-header': Header
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('tryAutoLogin')
  }
}
</script>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li v-if="!auth">
          <router-link to="/signup">Sign Up</router-link>
        </li>
        <li v-if="!auth">
          <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
        </li>
        <li v-if="auth">
          <router-link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
        </li>
        <li v-if="auth">
          <a @click="onLogout">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    auth () {
      return this.$store.state.token !== null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onLogout () {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route () {
      console.log('STORE: ', this.$store.state)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The errors:

[image: The errors]

Comment: What is the 'something' you are trying to access? If it is 'token' you need `this.$store.state.token` or if it's an action `this.$store.dispatch.???`

Comment: @Andrew1325 I am attempting to access `this.$store.dispatch('tryAutoLogin')` in App.vue, and `this.$store.state.token` in Header.vue. I've attached my code for Header.vue and a screenshot of the errors to the bottom of my post.

Comment: In `store.js`, `import Vue from 'Vue'` looks wrong. The import should be from `'vue'` (all lowercase) though I guess if you're on a case-insensitive filesystem, this won't be a problem

Comment: if you console.log() "this.$store" what do you get and if it is undefined what do you get if you just log "this" to the console?

Comment: @Phil Wow, you were right! The problem was my capitalization of 'Vue'. Such a tiny mistake was breaking everything. Is there a way to be notified of small typos like these? The webpack-dev-server compiler did not catch it.

Comment: When I tried it in my Vue CLI3 test app, it reported _"This dependency was not found:

* Vue in ./src/store.js"_ but then I am using a case-sensitive filesystem. If you're not using Vue CLI3 (which I think you are not), I highly recommend it

Comment: @Phil Thanks so much! If you turn your comment into an answer I will select it as the correct one.

Comment: @torjinx it's really just a typo. Doesn't need an answer

Comment: @Phil Naw, you should earn reputation for helping me, and the answer could help others in the future. I had no idea a tiny syntax error like that could cause `this.$store` to be undefined, and I didn't know my compiler wasn't catching the error because I was using Vue CLI2 instead of Vue CLI3.

Answer (score 0):

Use Destructuring when importing `store` into your `main.js` file.

Change your code from

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

To

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from './router'
import { store } from './store' //Added Destructuring

Vue.config.productionTip = false
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

It worked for me..Hope it works for you as well!

Answer (score -2):

Everything looks good in your code. However in your main.js file change the following code

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router,
 store,
 components: { App },
 template: '<App/>'
})
```

to

```
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   router,
   store,
   render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said but unfortunately it did not solve my problem. :( What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any difference but that works for me. Can you show the exalt error that is generated. I am referring to 
 this.$store.dispatch('tryAutoLogin')

Comment: When you say it works for you, do you mean you tried running my code with your modification and it worked? I've attached a screenshot of the errors to the bottom of my post.

Comment: OP would be getting a different error if the code in this answer was required. It would say _"You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build"_

Comment: Yes I said it worked for me because I implemented the same authentication code as yours with the little modifications I showed you. But thanks to Phil he has identified the problem in your code and added more light to mine.